# not displaying this alert ---> alert("I am inside change");

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

- I am trying to learn jquery.
- in jquery I am using change method.
- but its not displaying this alert ---> alert("I am inside change");
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/b8yx6f16/

```or-tag-here
 $('#checkIDGrid').change(function() {
     alert("I am inside change");
    if(this.checked) {
        var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
        $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
    }
   // $('#textbox1').val(this.checked);        
});
```

Comment: coudl you post the html including `#checkIDGrid`?

Comment: You should include just the relevant part of the code in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: A good tip is to add `alert($('#checkIDGrid').length)` just before your `.change()` code - if it alerts "0" then the element doesn't exist and your event handler will have nothing to wire up against.   If the element is created *after* this, then you have "dynamically generated elements" and need to use either event delegation or re-write the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $(document).on('change', '#checkIDGrid', function() {
         alert("I am inside change");
        if(this.checked) {
            var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
            $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
        }
       // $('#textbox1').val(this.checked);        
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wj1z3dnp/

Comment: hey can you explain your code so that in future I can solve it by myself

Comment: Basically for the dynamic elements, in order for your event handler to be executed, you can either call `$("#id").on("click", fn);` after you insert them into the DOM, or bind the event to a static element that always in the DOM, such as `$(document)`. My code here is doing the latter.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `#checkIDGrid` doesn't exist on the page until the grid populates, but the `change` event listener is bound immediately. You can use a delegate binding to avoid this issue:

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkIDGrid', function() {
```

A delegate binding is attached to a parent element and is triggered even if the child element is added to the DOM after the listener is attached.